# How to convert SQL Server CTE query to normal query

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a `DeviceCategory` table like this

[image]

In the table, the `CategoryID` column is a child of `CategoryParentCode`. I want to query to get all children of a parent.

This task can do by using a CTE query:

```
WITH CTE_DEVICE_CATEGORY (CID, CParentCode, CName, CCode, CDescription, EmpLevel) AS
(
    SELECT 
        CategoryID, CategoryParentCode, CategoryName, CategoryCode, 
        CategoryDescription, 1
    FROM
        DeviceCategory
    WHERE 
        CategoryParentCode = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        e.CategoryID, e.CategoryParentCode, e.CategoryName, e.CategoryCode, 
        e.CategoryDescription, r.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM 
        DeviceCategory e
    INNER JOIN 
        CTE_DEVICE_CATEGORY r ON e.CategoryParentCode = r.CID
)
SELECT
    CID, CParentCode, CName, CCode, CDescription
FROM 
    CTE_DEVICE_CATEGORY 
ORDER BY 
    EmpLevel, CParentCode
```

I don't want to use `WITH AS` so I have a question is how to convert such CTE query to a normal query (that does not use CTE)

Can everybody help me?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You can't. That's a recursive query, that traverses your hierarchical data - which requires a CTE.

Comment: You have a hierarchical data structure.  The way to traverse such a structure is using a recursive CTE.  This is a "normal" query.

Comment: Thanks, but i use EntitySpaces ORM, that does not support CTE, that's why i want to convert from CTE to normal query

Comment: Create a View that contains your CTE and query that from EntitySpaces

Comment: @AdamCooper but in View, i can not change query parameter (in my query above, i want to query by CategoryParentCode  value). Did you use EntitySpaces before? Can you point me some hints or code? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you use an Inline Table Valued Function? Its like a view, but takes parameters.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks, i will give a try

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of temp table and a while loop. For example:

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE DeviceCategory(CategoryID int, CategoryParentCode int, CategoryName nvarchar(50), CategoryCode int, CategoryDescription nvarchar(100));

INSERT INTO DeviceCategory(CategoryID , CategoryParentCode , CategoryName , CategoryCode , CategoryDescription)
SELECT  10, 0,  'k',    7,  'fvvfv'
UNION ALL SELECT    2,  10, 'b',    4,  NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    3,  3,  'c',    NULL,   NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    4,  9,  'd',    NULL,   NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    5,  1,  'e',    NULL,   NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    6,  10, 'f',    NULL,   NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    7,  4,  'g',    NULL,   NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    8,  8,  'h',    NULL,   NULL
UNION ALL SELECT    9,  6,  'i',    NULL,   NULL
```

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (CategoryID int, CategoryParentCode int, CategoryName nvarchar(50), CategoryCode int, CategoryDescription nvarchar(50), EmpLevel int);

DECLARE @i int=1;

INSERT INTO #temp(CategoryID, CategoryParentCode, CategoryName, CategoryCode, CategoryDescription, EmpLevel)
SELECT dc.CategoryID, dc.CategoryParentCode, dc.CategoryName, dc.CategoryCode, dc.CategoryDescription, @i
FROM DeviceCategory dc 
WHERE CategoryParentCode = 0;

WHILE @i>0
begin
    INSERT INTO #temp(CategoryID, CategoryParentCode, CategoryName, CategoryCode, CategoryDescription, EmpLevel)
    SELECT dc.CategoryID, dc.CategoryParentCode, dc.CategoryName, dc.CategoryCode, dc.CategoryDescription, @i+1
    FROM DeviceCategory dc INNER JOIN
    #temp tmp ON tmp.CategoryID=dc.CategoryParentCode
    WHERE tmp.EmpLevel=@i;

    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        SET @i=0;
    end
        ELSE 
    begin
        SET @i+=1;
    end

end

SELECT t.CategoryID, t.CategoryParentCode, t.CategoryName, t.CategoryCode, t.CategoryDescription
FROM #temp t
ORDER BY t.EmpLevel, t.CategoryParentCode

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
```

Let me know if this works for you.

**EDIT:**
You could also use table variable @temp instead of #temp if the number of rows is not very big.

Comment: Thanks,i tried your code but it returned nothing

Comment: I tested it and it worked on my side... I edited my answer to show you sample DeviceCategory data that I used. When executing your CTE and my loop result is the same so maybe there is no data in DeviceCategory table with CategoryParentCode = 0?